# EventNames of PowerShell jobs started with Start-Job

Tags: windows, powershell, start-job, powershell-jobs

I want to run a script when a PowerShell job has successfully completed. But how do I find out all possible events of the job started with the `Start-Job` cmdlet?

Here is an example:

```
$myjob = Start-Job { Get-ChildItem }

$jobEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $myjob -EventName StateChanged -Action {
    Write-Host 'Job has completed'
}
```

So from some other examples on Stack Overflow I know that there is `StateChanged` event, but it only tells that a state of a job has changed. Is there any event that would tell that the job has failed or completed successfully?

How do I get a list of such events? Is there any event besides `StateChanged`?

Or does the code have to inspect the job using `Get-Job` after receiving the `StateChanged` event to determine the job's actual state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`StateChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.job.statechanged?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) is the only event you can subscribe to for the [`Job` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.job?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0), it is enough though for what you're looking to accomplish.

In the `Action` block of your event there are different automatic variable that get automatically populated at event trigger: `$Event`, `$EventArgs`, `$args`, `$EventSubscriber` and `$Sender` which you can use to determine if your Job completed successfully or not. See [**about Automatic Variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2) for more details.

In this case I believe you could use the [`JobState.State` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.jobstateinfo.state?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-jobstateinfo-state) from your Job and check if its equal to [`Completed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.jobstate?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0). You could also check the `.Reason` property in case of a failure though this property may not always be populated.

```bash
$jobEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $myjob -EventName StateChanged -Action {
    switch($EventArgs.JobStateInfo.State) {
        Completed { Write-Host ('Job [{0}] completed successfully.' -f $sender.InstanceId) -ForegroundColor Green }
        Failed { Write-Host ('Job [{0}] failed.' -f $sender.InstanceId) -ForegroundColor Red }
        Default { <# something else here, enum has many possible states #> }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mklement0 my thought was any of the states in the `enum` could trigger the event but tbh I dont know

Comment: @mklement0 to be fair, after some testing, can't even get jobs to be in those states so you're most likely right

Comment: Hmmm... at least at first glance I see no attempt to filter regarding what states trigger an event: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/f8cbf90ccb7930e23c7f938256c3f361b3384ad5/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/remoting/client/Job.cs#L1380 (look for `StateChanged.SafeInvoke(`)

Comment: I went _partway_ down the rabbit hole: `NotRunning` is the _initial_ state and therefore never reported. All others do seem to be reported, including `Running` - assuming you subscribe in time; with `Start-Job`, it's usually too late, but with `Start-ThreadJob` you do see this state change. `Stopping` (as opposed to `Stopped`) is seemingly only raised if the job has _child_ jobs. Not sure about `Suspending`, which seems to relate to WinPS-only workflows.

Comment: @mklement0 thats good to know I guessed some of them could be hard to trigger due to timing, might be worth adding an answer with this additional information